# Find common elements from arrays's which are inside an Object - Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have an Object that contains multiple arrays

```
x = {
    c: ['Full_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Email', 'Organizations', 'MISC', 'UNIQUEID']
    small: ['Title', 'Organizations', 'URL', 'UNIQUEID']
    .
    .
    .}
```

What is the best and the fastest way to find all the similar elements from all these arrays?

So for example in this case the answer will be `['Organization', 'UNIQUEID']`

Comment: check stackoverflow for array intersection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript

Comment: What should happen if one of the arrays in `x` is `[]`? Should that always produce an empty array as the result? Or should the result array still contain some values since, for example, "UNIQUEID" is in more than one (but not all) arrays in `x`?

Comment: Then it should give an empty array as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a possible approach using `reduce` and `Set`. for the accumulator I'm initializing it with the first array (`x.c`). Doesn't matter which one since in the end we are taking intersection anyway. Inside the reduce I'm intersecting the accumulator with the current iteration array

```js
const x = {
  c: ['Full_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Email', 'Organizations', 'MISC', 'UNIQUEID'],
  small: ['Title', 'Organizations', 'URL', 'UNIQUEID'],
  big: ['abc', 'Organizations', 'def', 'UNIQUEID']
}


const res = Object.values(x).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return new Set(curr.filter(i => acc.has(i)))
}, new Set(x.c))

console.log([...res])
```

almost similar with a for loop except I'm skipping first element in loop

```js
const x = {
  c: ['Full_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Email', 'Organizations', 'MISC', 'UNIQUEID'],
  small: ['Title', 'Organizations', 'URL', 'UNIQUEID'],
  big: ['abc', 'Organizations', 'def', 'UNIQUEID']
}

const values = Object.values(x)
let acc = new Set(values[0])
for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
  acc = new Set(values[i].filter(j => acc.has(j)))
}

console.log([...acc])
```

Comment: isnt it intended im not sure

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a Set `intersection` -

```js
function intersection2(a, b) {
  if (a.size > b.size)
    return intersection2(b, a)
  const r = new Set
  for (const v of a)
    if (b.has(v))
      r.add(v)
  return r
}
```

You can compute the intersection of many sets by combining `reduce` and `intersection2` -

```js
function intersection(s, ...sets) {
  return sets.reduce(intersection2, s)
}
```

To use it with your code, get all values of `x` using `Object.values` and `map` over them to create an array of sets. Finally call `intersection` with all of the sets -

```js
const x = {
  c: ['Full_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Email', 'Organizations', 'MISC', 'UNIQUEID'],
  small: ['Title', 'Organizations', 'URL', 'UNIQUEID'],
  big: ['abc', 'Organizations', 'def', 'UNIQUEID']
}

const result =
  intersection(...Object.values(x).map(v => new Set(v)))

console.log(result)
```

```js
Set [ "Organizations", "UNIQUEID" ]
```

If you want the result as an array, you can convert it using `Array.from` -

```js
console.log(Array.from(result))
```

```js
[ "Organizations", "UNIQUEID" ]
```